# Google maps- Add new markers without initializing map each time

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-markers

This is what I want to do: I ask the user to type a latitude+longitude into an input box and I want to show a marker on the map for that location, without having to initialize the map every time.

I have initialized a map as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var myOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.053228, -118.259583),
          zoom: 12,
          zoomControl: true,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    });
</script>
<div style='height: 400px;'>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; float: left; height:100%"></div>
</div>
```

No jazz till now, this is the normal way of defining a map. Now, I have an input box, where I ask the user to type an address:

```
<input type="text" size=30 name="lat" id="lat">
<input type="text" size=30 name="lon" id="lon">
<button type="button" id="address_submit">Search</button>
```

I want to show the marker for that address. I defined a function, shown below, but am not getting how to show get the map object:

```
    $("#address_submit").live("click", function() {
    lat = $("#lat").val();
    lon = $("#lon").val();
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
          map: map, //HOW DO I GET THIS MAP OBJECT??
          title:"Hello World!"
      });
}
```

Comment: map object is undefined. Now I saw in google maps documentation that there is a getMap function, but there is no explanation or example on how to use it.

Comment: may be problem with variable initialization.Once try to initialize outside the ready function or script and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your code in a jsfiddle => http://jsfiddle.net/HaDbR/ and all seems to work as expected (I've reduced a bit the zoom factor just to see inserted markers): I've inserted some coordinates in the form (near to the map center coords) and the markers appeared correctly.

The only real differences is the visibility of `map` variable so that the `click` handler applied to the button can see it, and the `.on()` method instead of `.live()`

I've inserted the googlemap API script, calling a callback function `createMap()` and in that function I've initialized the map and I've associated the handler, so by closure it can have access to your map